# import org.testng.annotations.*; Can not be resolved

Tags: selenium, annotations, testng

I have successfully installed TestNG and confirmed in eclipse (4.9.0) as well. But while creating a basic class without main class i am getting error at the annotation @Test. Even after importing the test annotations package and the error is present on package as well. and error states it can not be resolved.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVPf1.png)

Comment: How does the question related to Selenium? Am I missing something?

Comment: i am using TestNG for selenium

Comment: How did you installed TestNG?

Comment: Do you have testng plugin for eclipse?

Comment: there was some problem in build path. its working now. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using maven project change scope test and add scope compile-

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId> testng </artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>  //replace test to compile 
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse you need to add testng library to your project after installation. Right click on project --> build path --> Add Libraries --> TestNG library,  then it will work

Answer (score 3):

Remove the module-info.java class from the project and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Download TestNg jar and add it to build path. It will resolve your issue.

Url: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng

Answer (score 0):

change JavaSE version to JavaSE-1.8

Answer (score 0):

Test annotations work only inside the main class. If you are trying to call Test annotations inside an extended class (a class that extends another class) then your test annotations will not work in this case.
In other words, @Test annotations should be inside the parent class, not the child class.

Answer (score 0):

You might have test scripts in src/main/java, hence can use default scope i.e 'compile' or remove it else recommended please move it to src/test/java and keep scope as 'test'

Answer (score -1):

Changing JavaSE version to JavaSE-1.8 works

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68292618/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*